# Is there a way to detect and deal with class overlap in ML.NET?

Tags: .net, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service, ml.net, data-preprocessing

What I have to do is that the user should be able to see the the percentage of overlaps also the defining the number of negatives falling on positives.
The system should detect if overlaps exists based on some user defined criteria. For example for numerical feature the users will define their own overlapping distance.
And after this choose a method to deal with it. In our case the method is to remove overlapped rows from false results as I have a binary classification with true/false.

I was wondering if ML.NET offers some transformers or estimator to help me with such task.

I went through some transformers but I couldn't get my way around them.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by defining a custom function to calculate overlaps based on your user-defined criteria and use the `CustomMapping` transformer to apply the custom function to your data as a custom data preprocessing steps before training your binary classification model.

> ML.NET does not offer any specific transformers or estimators to help with this task.

Below is a sample code to do this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;
using Microsoft.ML.Transforms;

public class InputData
{
    [LoadColumn(0)] public float Feature1;
    [LoadColumn(1)] public float Feature2;
    [LoadColumn(2)] public bool Label;
}

public class OverlapOutput
{
    public bool Overlap;
}

public class Program
{
    public static bool DetectOverlap(InputData data, float overlapDistance)
    {
    //(Change the logic as per need)
        return data.Label == true || (Math.Abs(data.Feature1 - data.Feature2) <= overlapDistance);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a new MLContext
        var context = new MLContext();

        // Read the data from a text file
        var data = context.Data.LoadFromTextFile<InputData>("data.txt", separatorChar: ',');

        // Calculate the percentage of overlaps and the count of negatives falling on positives (Change the logic as per need)
        int overlapCount = 0;
        int negativeOnPositiveCount = 0;
        int totalCount = 0;
        var dataEnumerable = context.Data.CreateEnumerable<InputData>(data, reuseRowObject: false);
        foreach (var row in dataEnumerable)
        {
            totalCount++;
            if (DetectOverlap(row, 0.5f))
            {
                overlapCount++;
                if (!row.Label)
                {
                    negativeOnPositiveCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        double overlapPercentage = (double)overlapCount / totalCount * 100;
        Console.WriteLine($"Percentage of overlaps: {overlapPercentage}%");
        Console.WriteLine($"Number of negatives falling on positives: {negativeOnPositiveCount}");

        // Define the custom mapping estimator
        var customMappingEstimator = context.Transforms.CustomMapping<InputData, OverlapOutput>((input, output) => output.Overlap = DetectOverlap(input, 0.5f), contractName: null);

        // Fit the custom mapping estimator to the data
        var customMappingTransformer = customMappingEstimator.Fit(data);

        // Transform the data using the custom mapping transformer
        var transformedData = customMappingTransformer.Transform(data);

        // Filter the rows based on the output of the custom function
        var filteredData = context.Data.FilterByCustomPredicate(transformedData, (OverlapOutput output) => !output.Overlap);

        // Display the output data
        var outputData = context.Data.CreateEnumerable<InputData>(filteredData, reuseRowObject: false);
        Console.WriteLine("Filtered data:");
        Console.WriteLine("Feature1, Feature2, Label");
        foreach (var row in outputData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{row.Feature1}, {row.Feature2}, {row.Label}");
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Data:

```
1.0,1.2,True
1.1,1.3,True
1.2,2.0,True
2.0,2.8,False
2.1,2.2,False
2.2,2.3,False
1.5,1.6,True
2.4,2.5,False
```

With above `sample code` and `sample data`, I'm able to preprocess the data.

[image]

For more details on `CustomMapping` please refer the this [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.custommappingcatalog.custommapping?view=ml-dotnet)